# Code review request: Architecture with one file per route, controller, and service

Tags: node.js, typescript, architecture, prisma

I am currently working on a NodeJS Express with TypeScript project, and I have organized my code using a structure where each route, controller, and service has its own file. For example, I have the following files:

```
├─ controllers
│  └─ auth.routes.ts
├─ routes
│  └─ auth.controller.ts
├─ services
│  └─ auth.service.ts
```

My goal in adopting this approach was to make the code more modular and easier to maintain. However, I am wondering if this is indeed the best practice and if it could potentially lead to scalability or performance issues as the project grows.

I would like to hear your opinions and experiences regarding this architecture. Does it make the code easier to understand and manage the features? Or does it make the project more complex as it grows? Are there any alternatives or improvements I could make to this structure to enhance code readability and maintainability?

I'd be grateful if you could take a look at this approach and give me your opinion on the best way to organize the code in a NodeJS project.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry much about it, structure is important but it's more important to be flexible in your ideas about it. When you get a better idea of the requirements as its scales you may have to refactor the structure and that's what you should be comfortable with. And the project should allow it.

About this in particular

```
├─ controllers
│  └─ auth.controller.ts
├─ routes
│  └─ auth.routes.ts
├─ services
│  └─ auth.service.ts
```

Nothing wrong about it but an extension defining `routes` within a `routes` folder gets redundant, generally I would go with something like

```
├─ auth
│  └─ auth.controller.ts
│  └─ auth.routes.ts
│  └─ auth.service.ts
```

You should also think about how much code is going to be common and how imports/exports work. In my experience when breaking things down like this into granular files, organising the distribution of common functionality can become problematic. You should also consider how much nesting this pattern and the project will require and if the structure accommodates for it.

```
├─ common
│  └─ common.controller.ts
│  └─ common.routes.ts
│  └─ common.service.ts
├─ auth
│  └─ auth.controller.ts
│  └─ auth.routes.ts
│  └─ auth.service.ts
```

or

```
├─ ...
|└─ common.controller.ts
│└─ common.routes.ts
│└─ common.service.ts
├─ auth
│  └─ auth.controller.ts
│  └─ auth.routes.ts
│  └─ auth.service.ts
```

can work.

Then if you find that at some point you're using 90% common code it's likely not even a problem as you just import it from a subdirectory.

But yea, would not focus too much on this. If you pay attention to the details as well and how the code is within the files, and have good tests. You should be in a position to change the structure if needed.